# Querying Active Directory in PowerShell from a Windows host that is not a member of the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, active-directory

How can I use PowerShell `[adsisearcher]` to query a domain that I am *not* a member of? Usually I will do something like this:

```
$myAdsi = [adsisearcher]""
$myAdsi.SearchRoot = [adsi]"LDAP://dc=corp,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
$myAdsi.Filter = "objectCategory=computer"

$res = $myAdsi.FindAll()
```

If I run this snippet on a host in my domain, I get the expected result. However, if I run this from a computer that has network access to the domain (through a L2L VPN) I get the error:

```
Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
"
At line:11 char:33
+ $adComputers = $searcher.FindAll <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

This is somewhat expected as I have not provided any sort of credentials to `[adsisearcher]` that would tell it how to authenticate. My question is: how do I let `[adsisearcher]` know that I want to authenticate against a domain in which I am not a member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited out my last reply. Sorry it took me a while to get back to you. The following is shamelessly copied from http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/26/chapter-19-user-management.aspx :

[ADSI] is a shortcut to the DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry .NET type. That’s why you could have set up the previous connection this way as well:

```
$domain = [DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]""
$domain
distinguishedName
-----------------
{DC=scriptinternals,DC=technet}
```

So try this to provide credentials to another domain:

```
$domain = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.10.10.1","domain\user", "secret")
$domain.name
scriptinternals
$domain.distinguishedName
DC=scriptinternals,DC=technet
```

You are right, it's an authentication problem, even though I wish the error message was more accurate to reflect that.  This should help you.

Comment: Yes, I can `nslookup` and `ping` `corp.mycompany.com`, with response originating from the DC responsible for the subnet that I am L2Ledd into

Comment: 1) All ports are open over the L2L

Comment: 2) I did not do a psexec or pssession but I did map a network drive with an administrator credential to get that going...

Comment: Edited my reply. Hope that helps you.